# How can I distribute a file across multiple systems in a network?

Tags: command-line

I have more than 60 ubuntu systems in my network. I want to copy files from one system to other ubuntu systems. All IP addresses are listed in a text file.

So what command can I use to complete the task? Any bash programs?

Comment: You sound frustrated. Please do not use that many question marks. What kind of file is it? Can't you setup a server from which the other computers download files from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose that you have your IP addresses in a file named ips.txt, each IP in a line. create a file named, for example *scp_all.sh* and copy the following text bellow in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE ; do
    scp $1 root@$LINE:$1
done < ips.txt
```

then execute it in this way:

```
./scp_all.sh /home/yaroo/Desktop/1.jpg
```

this is a really simple script, while it supposes that your username in all computers is root, it doesn't store password and you have to enter it each time, and it doesn't have any exception handler. 
if you want to change the destination address, change the second *$1* in scp command with $2 and use the script in this way:

```
./scp_all.sh /home/yaroo/Desktop/1.jpg /home/yaroo/Downloads/just_copied.jpg
```

I've said that you have to enter your password for each computer, but if you have decided to use this script regularly, you can solve this problem by this simple 6-step solution described [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8600).
good luck ;-)

Comment: just to mention that I haven't test this script! hope for best ;-)

Comment: Nice answer.  I'll just add that I would change the first line to `#! /bin/bash -e` so that it will stop if any of the commands fail.

Comment: Can you explain this line  `scp $1 root@$LINE:$1` ?

Comment: @karthick87 yeah, we store the address of source file in a variable named $1 (we get it from command line) and the IP address of destination machine in a variable named $LINE; so we copy file $1 to machine $LINE in the same address of $1. also root@$LINE means login at machine with IP address $LINE with username `root`. OK? ;-)

Comment: Yeah thankyou..But suppose if one of the system is down..Will it skip and go to the other system??

Comment: @karthick sorry, dunno ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Lekensteyn is correct -- you should probably be pulling the files from the server, rather than pushing them to the clients from the server.

If you're going to be doing this regularly (especially with a large number of files), I would set up [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) or a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) such as [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), rather than FTP, so that the clients only have to download things that have changed.

Comment: Or a configuration manager such as Puppet, bcfg2, Chef, etc.

Comment: @geekosaur That comment is worthy of answerhood. I'll upvote it once you make it so.

Answer (score 1):

(upgrading from earlier comment)
You may also want to look into a configuration management system such as [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com), [bcfg2](http://trac.mcs.anl.gov/projects/bcfg2), or [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/) to manage distributing files across a network.